# Saving a excel sheet as pdf

Tags: vba, pdf, excel

[image]I'm trying to save a excel sheet as a pdf through vb code(excel vba). After saving the pdf, i have symbol of question mark on the pdf page. How do i stop this?
 I have used the following code to save the pdf.

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "C:\Tracker\MoM.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard,    IncludeDocProperties:=True,IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

Comment: You mean a watermark?

Comment: No.... a question mark inside a box... like thus [?]... i couldn't include square box, so have put square braces just to show you how it looks

Comment: Could you take a screenshot and show?

Comment: I have shared the snap along with the question now

Comment: I have got to know this is because of the vbNewLine command, but i want new line character to be still present without getting the question mark

Comment: I think it's more the content in Excel rather than the PDF? Is there something special around "Leave of Absence" in your Excel?

Comment: No it's just a string in excel(in a cell)...yes it is related to the content of the excel

Comment: @t.thielemans is correct here I believe. Click on that cell and press `F2` Place your cursor at the end of the word `Absence` and press delete couple of times and then try again.

Comment: I need to the problem to be solved using vba code... no manual intervention should be there

Comment: My guess is the problem character is just that - a problem character. I used code to add vbNewline to a cell and it exported fine. How was the sheet generated?

Comment: ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "C:\Tracker\MoM.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard,IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
     IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

Comment: with the above code, i'm generating the pdf

Comment: I'm getting those question marks even when i save the excel sheet manually, by doing save as pdf

Answer (score 0):

I am doing conversion with the following code without any issues

```
With ActiveSheet
        .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PdfFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
     End With
```